# Get tags user commented of blogpost on

Tags: python, django-views, django-queryset, django-taggit

I am building a Blog App and I am trying to get all the tags which a user commented and that comment's blog was attached with tags.

*For Example :-** If a blog_1 has tags named `tag_1`, `tag_2` and `tag_3` and user commented in it and in any of these blog posts before.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    query = Tag.objects.filter(taggit_taggeditem_items__blogpost__user=request.user)

    context = {'query':query}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

But it is showing

> Cannot query "test_user": Must be "TaggedItem" instance.

Then i tried

```
query = BlogPost.objects.filter(taggit_taggeditem_items__blogpost__user=request.user)
```

It also showed the same error.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve here. You want to get tags of all Blog posts on which a user has commented. If this is correct, here is what I think:

I have defined my own models below to support my answer. Tweaked the `BlogPost` model a bit to include author field instead of user and defined a `Comment` model that has information about the `User` who commented and the `BlogPost` they commented on. I am assuming that the user that you have mentioned in the question is the one that commented and not the one that wrote the `BlogPost`.

```
class BlogPost:
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

class Comment:
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_post = models.ForeignKey(
                         BlogPost, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,  
                         related_name="blog",
                         related_query_name="blog_comment")
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

In your views, you can now use the [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) to query to get all the `BlogPost`s with `Comment`s by a specific `User` and access the tags of all those `BlogPost`s.

```
blog_post_tags = BlogPost.objects.filter(
                    blog_comment__user=request.user).values_list('tags', flat=True)
```

I have not used `taggit` before but I did not find any [documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) where you can directly query the `Tag` model.